# How to find the surface area of revolution of $x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1, 0 \le \le 1$ around the $y$-axis?

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

I am trying to solve this problem, but I have a hard time understanding how to solve it. The question is to find the area of the resulting surface...

$x^{2/3} + y^{2/3} = 1, 0 \le  \le 1$    around the y-axis

I am thinking to put...

The derivative is $-1/x^{1/3}.$

I am stuck on this problem, please help!

Comment: Three demensions?

Comment: Did you want to write $x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}$? To me, $x^2/3$ means "$x$ squared divided by $3$"...

Comment: Yes, that’s one. I’m sorry I’m new to this website so yeah.

Comment: @star3033 Now the title and question don't match.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown I fixed it, is that better now?

Comment: Can you draw the curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surface area is
$$2\pi\int_0^1 x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2}\,dy.$$
Here,
$$x=(1-y^{2/3})^{3/2}$$
so that
$$\frac{dx}{dy}=-y^{-1/3}(1-y^{2/3})^{1/2}$$
and
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2=y^{-2/3}(1-y^{2/3})=y^{-2/3}-1.$$
The integral is
$$2\pi\int_0^1(1-y^{2/3})^{3/2}y^{-2/3}\,dy.$$
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Lord Shark the Unknown's answer
$$I=\int(1-y^{\frac 23})^{\frac32}y^{-\frac23}\,dy$$ let $$y=\sin^3(t)\implies dy=3 \sin ^2(t) \cos (t)\,dt$$ which makes
$$I=3 \int \cos^4(t)\,dt$$ and
$$\cos^4(t)=\frac{1}{8} \cos (4 t)+\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 t)+\frac{3}{8}$$